# constexpr and bizzare error

Tags: c++, c++11, constexpr

I'm having:

```
constexpr bool is_concurrency_selected()const
    {
        return ConcurrentGBx->isChecked();//GBx is a groupbox with checkbox
    }
```

and I'm getting error:

```
C:\...\Options_Dialog.hpp:129: error: enclosing class of 'bool Options_Dialog::is_concurrency_selected() const' is not a literal type
```

Any thoughts on why?

Comment: Why do you add the const after the function?
It's already a constexpr

Comment: `return ConcurrentGBx->isChecked()` is this also a constexpr? What compiler on what OS?

Answer (score 6):

It means your class is not a literal type... This program is invalid, because `Options` is not a literal class type. But `Checker` is a literal type.

```
struct Checker {
  constexpr bool isChecked() {
    return false;
  }
};

struct Options {
  Options(Checker *ConcurrentGBx)
    :ConcurrentGBx(ConcurrentGBx)
  { }

  constexpr bool is_concurrency_selected()const
  {
      //GBx is a groupbox with checkbox
      return ConcurrentGBx->isChecked();
  }

  Checker *ConcurrentGBx;
};

int main() {
  static Checker c;
  constexpr Options o(&c);
  constexpr bool x = o.is_concurrency_selected();
}
```

Clang prints

```
test.cpp:12:18: error: non-literal type 'Options' cannot have constexpr members
    constexpr bool is_concurrency_selected()const
                   ^
test.cpp:7:8: note: 'Options' is not literal because it is not an aggregate and has no constexpr constructors other than copy or move constructors
    struct Options {
```

If you fix this and make the `Options` constructor `constexpr`, my example snippet compiles. Similar things may apply to your code.

You appear to not understand what `constexpr` means. I recommend reading a book about it (if such a book exists already, anyway).